# Magento live store is not working on Localhost

Tags: magento, localhost

I have created a copy of my live Magento store on my localhost and used the same db file but it displays this error message:

> There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is
>   disabled by default for security reasons.

Please someone tell me the reason.Please help me with this issue. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Error log record number: 350810859

```
 1. a:4:{i:0;s:93:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
    'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:2492:"#0
    D:\workspace_php\abc_store\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(96):
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() 
    D:\workspace_php\abc_store\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(313):
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() 
    D:\workspace_php\abc_store\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(459):
    Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
    #3 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238):
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
    #4 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(419):
    Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
    #5 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(169):
    Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
    #6 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(110):
    Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql',
    Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
    #7 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(320):
    Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
    #8 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(350):
    Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
    #9 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(335):
    Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
    #10 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
    #11 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(455):
    Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
    #12 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(497):
    Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
    #13 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1183):
    Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
    #14 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(414):
    Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
    #15 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(294):
    Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
    #16 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(413):
    Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
    #17 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343):
    Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
    #18 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #19 D:\workspace_php\abc_store\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:12:"/abc_store/";s:11:"script_name";s:21:"/abc_store/index.php";}
```

Comment: please paste the error message which is their in the 350810859 here.which you can find in the var/report/350810859.so that it will be easy to debug the error.

Comment: You need to change your DB settings from app/etc/local.xml file in order to make it work on your localhost.Also change base secure url and unsecure url of your localhost from core_config_data table.

Comment: Is it installation related issue?

Comment: First on the errors directory, change the file name /errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml

Comment: @Vickram: did that.but not working

Comment: @Asifhhh: changed but not working

Comment: please paste the error log message from the var/report/350810859

Comment: @PradeepSanku: updated my question with the error.

Comment: in your app/etc/local.xml you need change the password.on your localhost can you able to login with password or not.update the same in local.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here issue is with database credentials. look in following file

```
 app/etc/local.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems a DB connection error.You can use the below credentials as sample and change them according your DB details in your **app/etc/local.xml** file

```
<host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
<username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
<password><![CDATA[your_password_if_any]]></password>
<dbname><![CDATA[your_db_name]]></dbname>
```

Also in your core_config_data table change value as below

```
web/unsecure/base_url - http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/
web/secure/base_url   - http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/
```

Comment: @Vickram:i have done all but i cannot find the issue

Comment: @DamForums Post your app/etc/local.xml details.Is it still showing the above error ? Basically its you should know correct host, user name and password.

Comment: @Vickram: i am 100% sure about the contents on local.xml.i am using the correct values

Comment: @DamForums try using your IP if localhost is not working

Comment: @vickram:now site is working. but the css and themes havent loaded.on both backend and front end.whsy is that?

Comment: @DamForums pls check the CSS and JS path which shoould be under skin folder and with your local IP address and not the Production one.Also what went wrong with local.xml file ?

Comment: i cleared cache file and session file.after that system is working

Comment: solved the css matter also. on core_config_data table, i have missed last "/" on the path. "http://localhost/fashionway/" instead of this "http://localhost/fashionway"..... Thanks for your support through out this.

Comment: @DamForums I am glad I could help you and I already posted the URL's to change in DB for secure and unsecure

Answer (score 0):

Your have to make virtual host for running the live magento and make changes in the file windows/system32/drivers/etchosts file.

You have to map localhost IP address to domain name.